# Bell and escape character in prompt string

Tags: prompt, escape-characters

My prompt string is printed using this statement,

```
printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' user host /home/user
```

Why does it need an escape character (`\033`) and a bell character (`007`)? 
When i ran the same command manually, it prints nothing.

When i removed the escape characters and gave the command as,

```
printf '%s@%s:%s' user host /home/user
```

it prints,

```
user@home:/home/user
```

which is easier to understand.

So, how does the escape characters, `\033` and `007` get converted to a shell prompt string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `\033` is an escape and it initiates the escape sequence up until and include the `;`. `\033]0;`. This initiates a string that sets the title in the titlebar of the terminal and that string is terminated by the `\007` special character.

See `man console_codes`:

```
   It accepts ESC ] (OSC) for the setting of certain resources.  In  addi‐
   tion  to  the ECMA-48 string terminator (ST), xterm(1) accepts a BEL to
   terminate an OSC string.  These are a few of the OSC control  sequences
   recognized by xterm(1):

   ESC ] 0 ; txt ST        Set icon name and window title to txt.
```

That you don't see any changes is probably because your prompt sets the title to the default title string on returning to the prompt. Try:

```
 PROMPT_COMMAND= ; printf '\033]0;Hello World!\007'
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the *escape sequence* starts with the *first* escape character `\033` and *ends* with the `\007` (ASCII **`ESC`** and ASCII **`BEL`**).

The `0` is a parameter, corresponding to *Ps* in the description for xterm, while the text after the semicolon is *Pt*:

```
        Ps = 0  -> Change Icon Name and Window Title to Pt.
        Ps = 1  -> Change Icon Name to Pt.
        Ps = 2  -> Change Window Title to Pt.
```

Both `\033]` and `\007` are *parts* of the escape sequence which can be changed to *other* characters.  The terminal treats the pair of bytes as a single control character (just as the 4 bytes `\007` are treated by `printf` as a single character).  Referring to [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), the section [C1 (8-Bit) Control Characters](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-C1-_8-Bit_-Control-Characters) may be helpful:

```
ESC \
     String Terminator (ST  is 0x9c).
ESC ]
     Operating System Command (OSC  is 0x9d).
```

in understanding the beginning of [Operating System Controls](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls):

```
OSC Ps ; Pt ST
OSC Ps ; Pt BEL
```

Using **`BEL`** (`\007`) to end an escape sequence is an anomaly.  It does not follow the standard ([ECMA-48](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/)).  Operating system controls should begin with either `ESC ]` or 0x9d, and end with `ESC \` or 0x9c.

Long ago, the developer(s) of xterm added an escape sequence for setting the title.  In X11R1 (1987), the program simply read the sequence until it got a nonprinting character.  Later, in X11R4 (1989), someone improved this by terminating on a **`BEL`** character.  The standard had been around longer than that, but the reason for choosing **`BEL`** rather than **`ST`** is not known.  Ultimately that was addressed in the late 1990s, by recognizing either (but keeping **`BEL`** as an alternative since many users relied on hardcoded behavior with **`BEL`**).